# Что делать если версия sdk не совпадает?

Tags: java, android

Насколько я понимаю такая проблема, я работаю с Camera2 API, для работы с этой библиотекой нужно чтоб в файле `grade` была указана `minSdk API 21`, но в таком случае при  запуске на телефоне я получаю такую ошибку

```
minSdk(API 21) > deviceSdk(API 16)
```

если в `grade` меняю на API 16, то в коде подсвечивает ошибки. Что делать в таком случае? или на моем телефоне я не смогу протестировать приложение?

Comment: ну, видимо, на телефоне не сможешь. используй эмулятор для Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сможете работать с классом [`Camera2`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) только на устройстве с API21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop) и выше. C этим ничего не поделать.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете программно, в коде, определить уровень `API` девайса и обращаться к нужному классу как-то так:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
{
    //новое апи
}
else
{
    //старое апи
}
```

Comment: ок, но если я правильно понимаю то как только приложение захочет воспользоваться необходимыми функциями из 21апи, то ничего не получиться. Так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, если вы запустите на 21 и выше то выполнится код из первого блока. Иначе - из второго. И да, вам надо будет постоянно делать эту проверку чтобы недопустить возможности вызова слишком новых методов на старых ОСях.